# Paragraph tag causing parent to increase width

Tags: html, css

I've got a basic layout that is a div with a thumbnail, floated left, then a div with some text in it (title, description, links) that floats lefts as well.  They're meant to be side-by-side but as soon as the browser is too narrow, it pushes the 2nd div below the first, rather than just decreasing its width.

I can't believe I'm stumped on this as it seems really simple.  I'd really appreciate some help!

**html**

```
<div class="stunting-video odd">
    <div class="thumbnail">
        <img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/LixKwLQiSGU/mqdefault.jpg" data-video-id="LixKwLQiSGU" class="show-video" alt="stunting video">
    </div>
    <div class="info">
        <p class="title">GTA V - Stunt practise 03</p>
        <p class="description">A play-through of a race created to practise a motorbike stunt in GTA V where you can jump from the docks to near the airport.  Race is available here...<br>
        <br>
        <span class="highlight">PS3:</span> <a href="http://rsg.ms/0330f82">http://rsg.ms/0330f82</a><br>
        <span class="highlight">Xbox360:</span> <a href="http://rsg.ms/4464ca5">http://rsg.ms/4464ca5</a><br>
        <br>
        Special credits to Cheddar for the 360 version.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**css**

```
body {
    background-color: rgb(20, 20, 20);
    color: rgb(238, 238, 221);
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 300;
    margin: 20px;
}
a {
    color: rgb(111, 178, 244);
}
.stunting-video {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.125);
    border-radius: 30px;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3) inset, -5px -5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9) inset;
    clear: both;
    margin: 10px 0;
    overflow: auto;
    padding: 5px 15px 15px;
}
.stunting-video .thumbnail {
    border: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    float: left;
    margin: 10px 20px 0 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.stunting-video .thumbnail img {
    border-radius: 15px 0 0 15px;
}
.stunting-video .info {
    float: left;
}
.stunting-video .title {
    color: rgb(245, 215, 122);
    font-size: 150%;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.stunting-video p {
    margin: 5px 0;
}
```

**js fiddle example of the above**

http://jsfiddle.net/yp7f0nz1/

Comment: Unfloat the `info` div - http://jsfiddle.net/yp7f0nz1/4/

Comment: That causes a problem if the text goes below the image though... http://jsfiddle.net/yp7f0nz1/5/  I want the info to be in a column to the right of the image

Comment: Just add `padding-left` to the info div sufficient to push it past the thumbnail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All that is required is to **not** float the `info` div and (based on other comments) add adequate `padding=left` so that the text does not wrap around the thumbnail.

```
.stunting-video .info {
    padding-left: 350px;;
}
```

[**Jsfiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/yp7f0nz1/7/)

EDIT

I was reminded that a table would do this automatically and. of course,  we have display:table / table-cell open to us.

Removing the floats and using

```
.stunting-video {
    display: table;
}
```

and

```
.stunting-video .thumbnail {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: top;
}

.stunting-video .info {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

[**JSfiddle Demo 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/yp7f0nz1/10/)

Comment: The problem I have with this is that it's not a static page.  The info is loaded dynamically, and I can't guarantee the size of the thumbnail.

Comment: Then you need JS....there is no `one size fits all solution` Unless you can limit the size of the thumbnail.

Comment: Sorry, but I can't believe that there's no pure css way of doing this very simple layout.  I could use a table and it would work 100%.

Comment: If a table will do it...use one. No reason not to.

Comment: @Archer you're making a big deal out of nothing. The info is loaded dynamically with what? PHP? Javascript? Ruby? CSS still applies.

Comment: @carlodurso I'm not "making a big deal out of nothing".  It's called doing something correctly.  Please butt out if you've got nothing constructive to say.

Comment: They both work, but the first one does work with less changes, which is better because there's obviously a lot more to the site than this snippet.  I guess I'll just have to ensure that image size *is* enforced.  Thanks again :)